# Nagios - how to use logical operators in args passed to NRPE server

Tags: arguments, nagios, nrpe

I need to use logical operators on the passed argument to NRPE as Strings.  the operator is also used by NRPE as the FIELD separator. Which is the splat or ! token.

different ways of quoting the passed arg.  no affect.

```
Nagios Command.cfg
define command{
        command_name    check_remote_container_broker_health
        command_line    $USER1$/check_jmx4perl $ARG1$ $ARG2$ $ARG3$
        }

Nagios Remote Service
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       alphprdfuse1i
        service_description             Container IPRCMT1 Broker Health
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_remote_container_broker_health!-a '--user iprcmtx --password G00gl3M3 --url http://localhost:9091/jolokia --mbean org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=amq,service=Health --attribute CurrentStatus --string --critical '!Good''
        }
```

NRPE server
NRPE.cfg

```
command[check_remote_container_non_heap_used]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_jmx4perl $ARG1$ $ARG2$
```

When NRPE evaluates the statement, it should perform as 
if return.string NOT EQUAL Good

but, NRPE is seeing this as a Field Delimiter

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the NRPE Server command to:

```
command[check_remote_container_broker_health]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_jmx4perl $ARG1$ '!$ARG2$'
```

on Nagios Server

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       alphprdfuse1i
        service_description             Container Delta FADEC Broker Health
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_remote_container_broker_health!-a "--user deltafadec --password B@dM0nk3y --url http://localhost:9093/jolokia --mbean org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=amq,service=Health --attribute CurrentStatus --string --critical" "Good"
        }
```

so to remove the ! from the args being passed to NRPE, and let NRPE command issue the logical NOT or !

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this thread](https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=25354) my guess would be that exclamation marks cannot be escaped in a `check_command`, you need to avoid them completely.

One way to do this is to move the exclamation mark somewhere else, like the command definition in the NRPE config.

Another could be to use `resources.cfg` and define a `$USERX` macro with a number that Nagios will resolve, which is probably the best thing to do in cases of passwords and such, but maybe not in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

thank you !!!

I did try using resources.cfg and adding a $USERn$ definition.  this did not work for me.
I did try forming the expression on the NRPE server, to accept special characters. This works. And this is all because we avoid the network security risks by allowing dirty characters and bash shell operators.  So, this is the BEST solution. it just takes some time understanding what's going on.  If you set the logging high, you can see how the macros break it all down. any hoot, here is my solution for a couple implementations.

I will share 2 examples and situations.

on NRPE server, NRPE.cfg

```
command[check_remote_container_broker_health]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_jmx4perl $ARG1$ '!$ARG2$'
```

on Nagios server

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       alphprdfuse1i
        service_description             Container PassThru Context State
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_remote_container_context_state!-a '--user passthru --password B@dC0mpany --url http://localhost:9090/jolokia --mbean org.apache.karaf:type=admin,name="PassThru MultiTenant" --attribute Instances --path "PassThru MultiTenant"/State --critical' 'Started'
        }
```

on NRPE server, NRPE.cfg

```
command[check_remote_container_context]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_jmx4perl $ARG1$ $ARG2$ $ARG3$ $ARG4$ '$ARG5$"$ARG6$"' $ARG7$
```

on Nagios server

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       alphprdfuse1i
        service_description             Container PassThru Context ExchangesCompleted
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_remote_container_context!-a "--user passthru" "--password B@dC0mpany" "--url http://localhost:9090/jolokia" "--mbean" "org.apache.camel:context=passthrumt1.core-com.ge.digital.passthru.coreCamelContext,type=context,name=" "com.ge.digital.passthru.coreCamelContext" "--attribute ExchangesCompleted"
        }
```

Summary
so, if you do not enable the use of special characters on the NRPE, and the sending of such characters from Nagios server to NRPE system, which is declared as a security risk and if you can to avoid using. so, it just becomes a string manipolation to determine what works.  basically, if you have any special characters in the Nagios request to NRPE, you need to break this statement in to several strings without the special characters, and apply the special characters on the NRPE side. NRPE will strip out all these characters on evaluation of message.

Comment: You may want to define a user macro in a resource file so that you can avoid the `--password B@dC0mpany` in your service definition. This is best practice as *"The CGIs will not attempt to read resource files, so you can set restrictive permissions (600 or 660) on them to protect sensitive information."* -- see the docs for more info.